# What type of output it this, and how can I iterate through this with php?

Tags: php, wordpress, list, gravity-forms-plugin

This is the output of a Wordpress gravity form repeatable list; but how can I easily iterate through this with php to output only the content of each line?

```
a:3:{
    i:0;s:25:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame";
    i:1;s:25:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame";
    i:2;s:25:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame";
}
```

Comment: This looks like PHP [`serialize`d](http://php.net/serialize) format.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `unserialize` function.

```
$serialized = 'a:3:{i:0;s:25:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame";i:1;s:25:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame";i:2;s:25:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame";}';

foreach (unserialize($serialized) as $row) {
    echo " – $row\n";
}
```

The example above outputs:

```
 – Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame
 – Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame
 – Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame
```